# Lemonade Game in Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I am writing the lemonade stand game in Java but I am having a bit of trouble trying to figure out the perfect recipe. I have most of the code done, except the math logic seems a little off. Please let me know if I can improve the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ///declaration of variables
    int playAgain;
    int days, customers = 120;
        int CUPS_PITCHER = 14;
        double money = 20.00, earned = 0;
        double [] cupsPrice = {0.93, 1.65, 2.77}, lemonsPrice = {0.98, 2.05, 4.38}, sugarPrice = {0.74, 1.63, 3.31}, icePrice = {0.99, 2.01, 3.95};
        //inventory
        ///string input
        String cupsS = "", lemonsS = "", sugarS = "", iceS = "";

        //int input values 
        int cups = 0, lemons = 0, sugar = 0, ice = 0;

        //String for Pitcher
        double priceCup;
        int lemonsPitcher, sugarPitcher, iceCup;

        ////array for items options
        String [] cupsOptions = {"25","50","100"};
        String [] lemonsOptions = {"10","30","75"};
        String [] sugarOptions = {"8","20","48"};
        String [] iceOptions = {"100","250","500"};

        int temperature;
        String [] weather = {"Sunny","Hazy","Cloudy","Overcast","Rainny"};

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to our Lemonade Stand Game");
    days = getDays();

        ///set flag for loops 
        boolean ingredients, cupsFlag, lemonsFlag, sugarFlag, iceFlag;
        boolean [] flag = {false,false,false,false};

        NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        String [] itemName = {"Cups","Lemons","Sugar","Ice Cubes"};
        String [][] itemOptions = {cupsOptions,lemonsOptions,sugarOptions,iceOptions};

        for(int i=1; i<=days; i++){

            /////random weather 
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomWeather = rand.nextInt(5);

            //random temperature from 59 to 99
            temperature = rand.nextInt(99-59) + 59;
            int response = 0;
            ///loop while not play game 
            while(response != 1){
                String[] options = new String[] {"Buy", "Play Game", "Cancel"};
                response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You currently have " + defaultFormat.format(money) + "    Day " + i + "\nCups: " + cups + "       *** Lemons: " + lemons + "\nSugar: " + 
                        sugar + "     *** Ice: "+ice + "\nHigh Temperature: " + temperature + "\nWeather Forecast: " + weather[randomWeather], "Inventory",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null, options, options[0]); 

                ingredients = false;
                ///if buy ingredientes ** when they click buy 
                while(response == 0 && !ingredients){
                    String[] optionsBuy = new String[] {"Buy Cups", "Buy Lemons", "Buy Sugar", "Buy Ice","Back to Game"};
                    String line1 = "\n25 Cups: $" + cupsPrice[0] + "          10 Lemons: $" + lemonsPrice[0] 
                            + "          8 Cups of Sugar: $" + sugarPrice[0] + "          100 Ice Cubes: $"+icePrice[0];
                    String line2 = "\n50 Cups: $" + cupsPrice[1] + "          30 Lemons: $" + lemonsPrice[0] 
                            + "          20 Cups of Sugar: $" + sugarPrice[1] + "        250 Ice Cubes: $"+icePrice[1];
                    String line3 = "\n100 Cups: $" + cupsPrice[2] + "        75 Lemons: $" + lemonsPrice[2] 
                            + "         48 Cups of Sugar: $" + sugarPrice[2] + "        500 Ice Cubes: $"+icePrice[2];
                    int responsePurchase = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You currently have " + defaultFormat.format(money) + "    Day " + i + line1 + line2 + line3 + "\nHigh Temperature: " + temperature + "\nWeather Forecast: " + weather[randomWeather], "Inventory",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null, optionsBuy, optionsBuy[0]);

                    double [][] priceOptions = {cupsPrice,lemonsPrice,sugarPrice,icePrice};
                    int [] qty = {0,0,0,0};
                    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                        if(responsePurchase == j)
                            qty[j] = buyItems(itemName[j],itemOptions[j],flag[j],money);
                            //money = money - itemPrice[j][0];
                        }

                    ///deduct money 
                    for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
                        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                            if(qty[k] == Integer.parseInt(itemOptions[k][j])){
                            money = money - priceOptions[k][j];
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    ////add items purchased
                    cups += qty[0];
                    lemons += qty[1];
                    sugar += qty[2];
                    ice += qty[3];

                    //System.out.println(itemOptions[0][1]);
                    /*
                    if(qty[0] == 25){
                        money = money - cupsPrice[0];
                    }
                    if(qty[0] == 50){
                        money = money - cupsPrice[1];
                    }
                    if(qty[0] == 100){
                        money = money - cupsPrice[2];
                    }

                    // buy lemons
                    cupsFlag = false;
                    if (responsePurchase == 0) {
                      int qty = buyItems("Cups",cupsOptions,cupsFlag,money);
                      if (qty != 0) {
                        cups += qty;
                      }
                    }

                    // buy lemons
                    lemonsFlag = false;
                    if (responsePurchase == 1) {
                      int qty = buyItems("Lemons",lemonsOptions,lemonsFlag,money);
                      if (qty != 0) {
                        lemons += qty;
                      }
                    }
                    */
                    ///go back to game when back to game click
                    if(responsePurchase == 4){
                        ingredients = true;
                    }
                }///end while buy ingredients
            }///end while buy

            JTextField fieldCup = new JTextField("0.25");
            JTextField fieldLemons = new JTextField("4");
            JTextField fieldSugar = new JTextField("4");
            JTextField fieldIce = new JTextField("4");

            Object[] fields = {"Price per Cup in Cents", fieldCup,"Lemons per Pitcher", fieldLemons,"Sugar per Pitcher", fieldSugar, "Ice per Cup", fieldIce};

            int responsePitcher = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,fields,"Price",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if(responsePitcher == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
                    int stopGame = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you wish to cancel the game? All progress will be lost","",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(stopGame == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            while(!validateDouble(fieldCup.getText()) || !validateInt(fieldLemons.getText()) || !validateInt(fieldSugar.getText()) || !validateInt(fieldIce.getText())){

                if(responsePitcher == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
                    int stopGame = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you wish to cancel the game? All progress will be lost","",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(stopGame == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"One of the inputs is incorrect! try Again","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                responsePitcher = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,fields,"Price",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            }

            priceCup = Double.parseDouble(fieldCup.getText());
            lemonsPitcher = Integer.parseInt(fieldLemons.getText());
            sugarPitcher = Integer.parseInt(fieldSugar.getText());
            iceCup = Integer.parseInt(fieldIce.getText());

            for(int k=0; k<5; k++){
                if(weather[randomWeather].equals(weather[k])){
                    ////if weather is not sunny reduce possible customers  
                    if(!weather[randomWeather].equals(weather[0])){
                       customers = customers - (customers * k/15);
                    }
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(customers);///testing results 
            //System.out.println(fieldCup.getText());///testing results 


            System.out.println(customers);///testing results
            //showBar();

            ///perfect recepie
            if(temperature > 58){
                ///if sunny
                if(weather[randomWeather].equals(weather[0])){

                }
            }

            //too expensive or not right ingredients reduce possible customers 
            if(priceCup > 0.25){
                customers = customers - (customers * 10/100);///reduce customers by 10% 
            }
            if(lemonsPitcher > 7 || lemonsPitcher < 5){
                customers = customers - (customers * 10/100);///reduce customers by 10% 
            }
            if(sugarPitcher > 7 || sugarPitcher < 5){
                customers = customers - (customers * 10/100);///reduce customers by 10% 
            }
            if(iceCup > 10 || iceCup < 6){
                customers = customers - (customers * 15/100);///reduce customers by 15% 
            }


            ///determine max cups according to inventory 
            int maxCupsLemons = (lemons / lemonsPitcher) * CUPS_PITCHER;
            int maxCupsSugar = (sugar / sugarPitcher) * CUPS_PITCHER;
            int maxCupsIce = (ice / iceCup);
            int maxCupsp = cups;

            int [] maxCups = {maxCupsLemons, maxCupsSugar, maxCupsIce, maxCupsp};

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxCups));

            int minValue = maxCups[0];  
            for(int m=0;m<maxCups.length;m++){  
                if(maxCups[m] < minValue){  
                    minValue = maxCups[m];  
                }
            }
            System.out.println(minValue);
            if(minValue < customers){
                customers = minValue;
            }  
            System.out.println(customers);///testing results
            ////profit 
            earned = priceCup * customers;
            money += earned;


            ///deduct inventory
            //14 cups per pitcher 
            int lemonsSpent = (customers / CUPS_PITCHER) * lemonsPitcher;
            int sugarSpent = (customers / CUPS_PITCHER) * sugarPitcher;

            lemons = lemons - lemonsSpent;
            sugar = sugar - sugarSpent;
            cups = cups - customers;


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your profit for day " + i + " is " + defaultFormat.format(earned));


            /////reset variables for next day
            customers = 120;
            earned = 0;
            ice = 0;
        }


    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,days);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What do you mean by _"the math logic seems a little off"_?

Comment: If this is a solution to a [tag:programming-challenge], then you need to state or summarize the challenge, and link to it if possible.

Comment: In addition, if the code is known to be working incorrectly, then it would be off-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 5):

My review will be mainly about form, as this seems to be a point which should be addressed.

---

#### Comments

The comments in your code seem mostly excessive. Your naming seems pretty good, but there are comments all over the place, many stating things that are pretty obvious...

> ```
> ///declaration of variables
> int playAgain;
> int days, customers = 120;
> ...
> ```

Any Java programmer would understand these are variable declaration, I'm not exactly sure why this is needed. Especially since the naming is OK, I personally think comments like that are unnecessary. There are comments like this one everywhere.

---

#### Declarations

Declaring a whole bunch of variables in a one-liner is generally not preferred:

> ```
>     ///set flag for loops 
>     boolean ingredients, cupsFlag, lemonsFlag, sugarFlag, iceFlag;
> ```

It takes more typing to declare each one, but it makes the code more clear when they are each declared on their own. It becomes especially confusing when you do things like:

> ```
> int days, customers = 120;
> ```

Better to do something like this:

```
int days; 
int customers = 120;
```

---

#### A little room to breathe

You have instructions like this:

> ```
> for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
> ```

Adding a bit of whitespace wastes a few key strokes, but makes the statement more clear:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
```

---

While we're on the topic, you use a lot of *"magic numbers"* like `4` here. Why is this `4` instead of another number? I think it would make the code much more comprehensible if you used variables instead, like:

```
int reasonThisIsFour = 4;
for(int k = 0; k < reasonThisIsFour; k++) {
```

---

#### Commented-out code

The @joanb a year from now may not remember all the intricacies of the code, and things like this might throw you for a loop later on:

> ```
>                 //System.out.println(itemOptions[0][1]);
>                 /*
>                 if(qty[0] == 25){
>                     money = money - cupsPrice[0];
>                 }
>                 if(qty[0] == 50){
>                     money = money - cupsPrice[1];
>                 }
>                 if(qty[0] == 100){
>                     money = money - cupsPrice[2];
>                 }
>
>                 // buy lemons
>                 cupsFlag = false;
>                 if (responsePurchase == 0) {
>                   int qty = buyItems("Cups",cupsOptions,cupsFlag,money);
>                   if (qty != 0) {
>                     cups += qty;
>                   }
>                 }
>
>                 // buy lemons
>                 lemonsFlag = false;
>                 if (responsePurchase == 1) {
>                   int qty = buyItems("Lemons",lemonsOptions,lemonsFlag,money);
>                   if (qty != 0) {
>                     lemons += qty;
>                   }
>                 }
>                 */
> ```

It's OK to comment out code while writing & testing it, but I think either you should remove dead/non-function code, or explain why it is commented out.

Comment: Thanks for the input I updated the code and the question too. I tried to be consistent declaring variables. The reason why all the commented out code is there is because I have to present to class on Monday and I left it there to do my presentation.

Comment: @joanb: Please don't update code based on answers, as that will invalidate them.

Comment: May I add extra code I came up with?

Comment: We would rather you ask a new question, if you have more code to be reviewed. You may also include the revised code in your new question.